# Prometheus Histogram Vector: All buckets fill equally?

Tags: go, prometheus

I intend to use a Prometheus Histogram vector to monitor the execution time of request handlers in Go.

I register it so:

```
var RequestTimeHistogramVec = prometheus.NewHistogramVec(
    prometheus.HistogramOpts{
        Name:    "request_duration_seconds",
        Help:    "Request duration distribution",
        Buckets: []float64{0.125, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7.5, 10, 20},
    },
    []string{"endpoint"},
)

func init() {
    prometheus.MustRegister(RequestTimeHistogramVec)
}
```

I use it so:

```
startTime := time.Now()
// handle request here
metrics.RequestTimeHistogramVec.WithLabelValues("get:" + endpointName).Observe(time.Since(startTime).Seconds())
```

When I do a HTTP GET to the `/metrics` endpoint after using my endpoint a couple of times, I get - amongst other things - the following:

```
# HELP request_duration_seconds Request duration distribution
# TYPE request_duration_seconds histogram
request_duration_seconds_bucket{endpoint="get:/position",le="0.125"} 6
request_duration_seconds_bucket{endpoint="get:/position",le="0.25"} 6
request_duration_seconds_bucket{endpoint="get:/position",le="0.5"} 6
request_duration_seconds_bucket{endpoint="get:/position",le="1"} 6
request_duration_seconds_bucket{endpoint="get:/position",le="1.5"} 6
request_duration_seconds_bucket{endpoint="get:/position",le="2"} 6
request_duration_seconds_bucket{endpoint="get:/position",le="3"} 6
request_duration_seconds_bucket{endpoint="get:/position",le="4"} 6
request_duration_seconds_bucket{endpoint="get:/position",le="5"} 6
request_duration_seconds_bucket{endpoint="get:/position",le="7.5"} 6
request_duration_seconds_bucket{endpoint="get:/position",le="10"} 6
request_duration_seconds_bucket{endpoint="get:/position",le="20"} 6
request_duration_seconds_bucket{endpoint="get:/position",le="+Inf"} 6
request_duration_seconds_sum{endpoint="get:/position"} 0.022002387
request_duration_seconds_count{endpoint="get:/position"} 6
```

From the looks of it, all buckets are filled by the same amount, equal to the total amount of times I used my endpoint (6 times).

Why does this happen and how may I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prometheus histogram buckets are cumulative, so in this case all the requests took less than or equal to 125ms.

In this case your choice of buckets may not be the best, you might want to make some of the buckets smaller.

Comment: Figured it out literally the moment you posted. I will adjust this.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an error. Notice the rule for filling the bucket is `le=...`, meaning *less or equal*. Since all 6 requests succeeded quickly, all buckets were filled.